# Set number of comments to return with Facebook API

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using the Facebook Javascript API, I am requesting all photos from a certain Facebook album:

```
FB.api('/'+albumid+'/photos?fields=id,picture,name,comments&limit=1000', function(photos) 
{
    //do something
})
```

Here, the limit parameter refers to the number of photos to return. Is there also a way to set the number of comments per photo to return? Or do I need to query /comments for each photo itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to specify limit of results for nested data from one of connections (like `comments` in that case).

For comments only small amount of last comments will be returned for each photo (if any). To get all comments for a photo you'll need to retrieve 'em from `/PHOTO_ID/comments`.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of... Thanks for pointing out though!